# The find method in node refuses to return all data from collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a backend for a twitter clone, every route is working fine however I ran into an error when I tried to get all users with their information, the code is as follows

```
router.get("/tweets", (req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then((user) => res.json(user))
        .catch((err) => res.json({ error: "an error occured", err }));
});
```

This is the error I keep running to after I make the get request in postman

```
(node:16836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "tweets" at path "_id" for model "User"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\hp\Documents\P. Languages\React\MERN\pro\client\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4351:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\hp\Documents\P. Languages\React\MERN\pro\client\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4443:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:16836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16836) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And the funny thing I used this same method to return all users in another code and it worked, so I don't know if it is because of the length of the schema that I am running into this issue or not.

This is the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255,
    },
    tweets: [
        {
            tweet: {
                type: String,
                createIndex: true,
                unique: true,
                date: Date.now,
            },
        },
    ],
    tweetNo: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    followers: [
        {
            default: [],
        },
    ],
    following: [
        {
            default: [],
        },
    ],
    numFollowers: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    numFollowing: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
});

userSchema.followers = [
    {
        type: userSchema,
    },
];

userSchema.following = [
    {
        type: userSchema,
    },
];

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And this is the sample data from Mongo db

```
_id:5f03c0f2c4cb6f43749fdcde
numFollowers:0
numFollowing:0
firstName:"Babagana"
lastName:"Abba"
email:"babagabba@gmail.com"
password:"$2b$10$3csAMnCf/3fRL5rwr9koMeaSkFBvZ2T5noiHG0QhI5XZHFOUjGHOm"
tweets:Array
 0:Object
  _id:5f03c0f2c4cb6f43749fdcdf
  tweet:"my name is Babagana"
 
tweetNo:1
followers:Array
following:Array
__v:1
```

Comment: Have you stored something with an _id field that is not the usual mongo object id?

Comment: @Ravi I did and it still showed the same error

Comment: @Matt yes I have

Comment: It looks like your mongoose model doesn't match the data. The model wants `_id` to be the standard object ID. When mongoose retrieves the data and tries to convert the `_id` field to it's `ObjectId` type that's failing. Update your model to match the data or fix the data.

Comment: add the model and sample data to the q if you need a specific answer.

Comment: @Matt I've added the model and the sample data to the question

Comment: You probably have another route like this `router.get("/:userId", ...)`, make sure `router.get("/tweets", ...)` get matched before that route by putting the `/tweets` route before `/:userId`

Comment: @thammada.ts this worked, thanks

Comment: @Babagee feel free to share how you have fixed it for your particular case and mark your own answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a route with id like so

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    ////////
});
```

But it was above the previous route in the question, so after I took the route above this one it got matched before it reached the bottom and it fixed the issue